# Exception in thread "main" error

Tags: java, user-interface

This is the only error that I see in my code.  It is this line:

```
public class VolCac extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
```

This is the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

```
at VolCac.main(VolCalc.java:810)
```

This is line 810:

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 
    JFrame frame = new CalcVolume(); 
    frame.setSize(525, 350); 
    frame.setVisible(true); 
                                      }
}
```

I can’t figure why I’m getting the error.

Comment: JFrame frame = new CalcVolume();  should be     JFrame frame = new VolCac();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Unresolved compilation problem" errors at rntime are what happens when your code doesn't compile, but you tell Eclipse to run it anyway. The exception will happen at the point where the program can't continue any longer.

In this case, I see a file named "VolCalc," a class named "VolCac", and an attempt to create an instance of "CalcVolume". I'm pretty sure you mean for all three of these to match!

Comment: @ Ernest, I changed all to match VolCalc and I get the following errors 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: VolCac Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: VolCac at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) Exception in thread "main" Even though I changed them to match.'

Comment: Well, as @Bozho suggests, "Project | Clean... | All" would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

That error implies you're running Eclipse. Regardless, your IDE should be telling you what's wrong on that line. I hope you don't really have ALL that code on one line as you imply!

Answer (score 0):

if you're using eclipse try to clean your project

and also your class name is VolCac and your are makine a new CalcVolume Object...

can't say much without seeing more code...